# How do I take a song's music and convert into single notes for a looping 3D animation video

Tags: sound-design, sound, techniques, ableton-live

I have this sound track that I want converted into single notes so that it can fit with my 3D looping animation:

I just want the whole track converted into notes without the vocals so they can fit on my 3d looping animation. One such example is this:

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/vde-uxFfvRE

I am a complete noob in sound design and I don't know anything.
If anyone can just guide me a little bit I'll be grateful.

Comment: I don't exactly know what that process of turning a whole song into individual beats so they can sync up to my animation is called, I've searched far and wide and so far I've come across the terms: vocal isolation, convert to instrumentals, quantization of beats etc.
I don't know what they all are supposed to mean so please help me on this.

Comment: @ToddWilcox yes, sorry for the mistake, complete noob here. I was trying to find ways online to convert the music into the single notes so they fit perfectly in rhythm for my music animation.

Answer (score 2):

first time even visiting here, hope I can help in some way.
I first would like to clarify the meaning of a "beat".

I think for most people here, a beat would first refer to the rhythmical concept, like if you count along to music while saying "1 2 3 4" or when you clap along to music.
I think [this video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F21pS3Wo8ko) can explain the musical/rhythmical concept of a "beat" better than I can.
You only need to watch until around 1:00, after that, the presenter goes into DAWs and other stuff, (which you can still watch if you're interested); I just don't think it's strictly necessary. You may also watch the timestamp about rhythm for a little context, though.

Anyways, another meaning of a "beat" is a musical piece that is made up only of instruments and can for example be used by a rapper to have a foundation for his rapping/singing. That means, the beat consists of the drums, the bass and the melody, and the rapper records their rapping on top of that.
See for an example "beat" [something like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjWwR5FGj1k).
From what I know, though, the term "beat" with this meaning is only or predominantly used in the rap and hip-hop communities. (If someone else knows better, I'm open for any corrections.)

---

So, I think the thing that you want is not "single beats" but rather a version of the song without the vocals (=singing), generally called an "instrumental" or "instrumental version".
If that is, in fact, what you want, then you have a couple ways of achieving this.

1. **remake the track**
   --->in short, quite a lot of effort (especially for someone with your prior knowledge, no front though), and outcome may not even be worth it at all
2. **put the song into a vocal-remover tool or stem-splitter**
   ---> You can find these sorts of tools online and for free quite often, the result is between "meh" and "okay" most of the times.
   For this option you have to have an actual music file (e.g. mp3 or wav or other file-format) on your device, which you may acquire through bandcamp or from ripping it from youtube or whatever, that's not quite my business to figure out for you.
3. **just use the existing instrumental from Charlie himself lol**
   ---> [there it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YR9MBFgx9QY), free for you to enjoy

---